# Return Data from Table Valued Function with Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have a query which contain table valued function. But when executing this attached error comming. How can I solve this?

```
SELECT bg.Description, im.ERPItemCode,
(select Opening,Topup1,Topup2,Topup3,
 Returnsv,SaleQty,SaleVal from dbo.GetOpeningByRepAcc(@Date,@RepAccId,@Cente![enter image description here][2]rId,im.Id)),
(select Name from dbo.DistributionCenter where Id = @CenterId) as center,
(select Name from dbo.SalesRepAcc where Id = @RepAccId)as repacc    
FROM BudgetGroup AS bg 
INNER JOIN  ItemMaster AS im ON bg.Id = im.BudgetGroupId
WHERE (bg.Active = 1)
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer apply` instead of subselect when you need to return more than one value from function:

```
select
    bg.Description, 
    im.ERPItemCode,
    T1.Opening,
    T1.Topup1,
    T1.Topup2,
    T1.Topup3,
    T1.Returnsv,
    T1.SaleQty,
    T1.SaleVal,
    (select Name from dbo.DistributionCenter where Id = @CenterId) as center,
    (select Name from dbo.SalesRepAcc where Id = @RepAccId)as repacc    
from BudgetGroup AS bg 
    inner join  ItemMaster AS im ON bg.Id = im.BudgetGroupId
    outer apply dbo.GetOpeningByRepAcc(@Date,@RepAccId,@CenterId,im.Id) as T1
where (bg.Active = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to return a single column when using your TVF as a subquery

In your code you return `Opening,Topup1,Topup2,Topup3,Returnsv,SaleQty,SaleVal` from your TVF

```
((select Opening,Topup1,Topup2,Topup3,
 Returnsv,SaleQty,SaleVal from dbo.GetOpeningByRepAcc(@Date,@RepAccId,@CenterId,im.Id))
```

You also need to make sure you only get a single row from your sub-queries. you can use `TOP 1` with `ORDER BY` to get only a single row

Comment: But my issue is if I select separately all the values, more time is taking.Is there any way to increase the performance?

Comment: you can use `outer apply` as suggested by Andy Korneyev